# /dev/sda5: clean, files ..., blocks.... AND PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected after nvidia-driver install

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 20.04, cuda

I have Dell laptop with Nvidia Quadro 620M with Ubuntu 20.04.2 (along some remnants of Windows) with kernel 5.8.0-48.

After installing Nvidia drivers the system won't boot: it does not reach the login screen and just displays the two messages from the heading.

Tried adding `pci=noaer` to GRUB, but it does get rid only of PCIe Bus Error, and the system still won't boot.

I tried purging Nvidia drivers with `sudo apt purge *nvidia*` and then the system boots, but when I tried reinstalling Nvidia drivers in any way the problem was always coming back.

Comment: Welcome! How exactly did you install the drivers? Using `apt` I assume, but what exactly did you install? Did you request `apt` only one package name, or multiple packages? Have you tried downloading and installing your drivers from [Nvidia's website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) ?

Comment: I installed it with cuda through nvidia archive following these steps: 
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal
as I needed cuda 10.0 to be compatible with caffe_unet; when problem appeared I purged everything and tried several ways: "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460", "ubuntu-drivers autoinstall", through graphical interface "Activities >> Software & Updates >> Additional Drivers" and choosing driver-460; from Nvidia website as you suggested - all ends up with the same problem

Comment: it seems that the reason is broken GPU: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/dev-sda5-clean-files-blocks-and-pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-after-nvidia-driver-install/173471/6